# Net-SNMP host snmpwalk

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I'm trying to get data on the host with net-snmp (5.6.1.1)

`snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.0.102 1.3.6.1.2.1.25
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::host = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`

Here's what it returns, the agent is configured on public to read-write and read-only.

Comment: Tip: If you don't ask a question you will not get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The queried device (192.168.0.102) most likely doesn't implement the [HOST-RESOURCES-MIB](http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/H/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.php), which is located beneath the 1.3.6.1.2.1.25 branch.

If you've just installed/enabled NET-SNMP, keep in mind that the default snmpd.conf configuration file is fairly restrictive regarding queries from different hosts. You will need to update the configuration file to publish data from this branch.

Answer (score 0):

It means the agent doesn't support any SNMP information underneath or at
the oid you requested.  Or it does, but you don't have access to it. (try it with 'private' community)

Comment: In the latter case you should have `noAccess` instead